# Is there a way to end a recursive method when a certain condition is met in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function which returns me a value and its size that can set on calculative label width. After met certain condition I want to stop further procedure of recursion function like **break**.

```
func getLength(value: Int, font: UIFont, viewFrame: CGRect) -> (width:CGFloat, text:String) {
    let width: CGFloat!
     var val = value

    let size = String(format:"%d",value).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    if size.width+10 > viewFrame.size.width {
        width = viewFrame.size.width-10
        val = val/10
        _ = getLength(value: val, font: font, viewFrame: viewFrame)
        return (0.0 , "")

    } else {
        width = size.width+10
        return (width,String(format:"%d+",val))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using recursive function you should return value on both condition

```
 func getLength(value: Int, font: UIFont, viewFrame: CGRect) -> (width:CGFloat, text:String) {
        let width: CGFloat!
         var val = value

        let size = String(format:"%d",value).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
        if size.width+10 > viewFrame.size.width {
            width = viewFrame.size.width-10
            val = val/10
            return getLength(value: val, font: font, viewFrame: viewFrame)

        } else {
            width = size.width+10
            return (width,String(format:"%d+",val))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return a value in the function rather than recursively calling the function again. That will stop the recursion, you'll return up the call stack, and return a value. In your case the recursion looks pointless, since you always return `(0.0, "")` if your `if` statement evaluates as true.